# Selenium, setting unique user for each parallel login

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have implemented parallel testing using Selenium and Nunit for a web application, and want somehow to use a unique user for each test. I thought maybe populating a dictionary with users for keys and a value of 1 each, and then updating the dictionary value every time a user is used so that the next test uses the first available user with a 1 value. However this is not working for me. Can anyone recommend any other possibilities to accomplish this?

Regards

Comment: `However this is not working for me` not very informative

Comment: It seems that as the tests run at exactly the same time the first one doesn't have time to update the dictionary before the second one reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the root cause issue is in your Fixture strategy. If you do really want unique user per test, you don't need to keep already used users. I would suggest you to look at the [Fresh Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html) pattern or use [any of the others](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html), which best suites you. Tests that depend on other tests are well known Test/code smell. You already have your tests running in parallel, why going back and relying on specific execution order (again dependency)!?

In case you still need to

> I thought maybe populating a dictionary with users for keys and a value of 1 each, and then updating the dictionary value every time a user is used so that the next test uses the first available user with a 1 value.

You can look at the [Object pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) pattern, since it allows you to:

> A client of the pool will request an object from the pool and perform operations on the returned object. When the client has finished, it returns the object to the pool rather than destroying it;

And since you are on the .Net stack, consider using [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Comment: Thanks. For now I've implemented SetUpFixture, and created a dictionary in there. By definition of SetUpFixture this is only created once before all tests. I then put a lock on the dictionary for each test to pick a user.